# Can an org clock table :match on things that aren't tags?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock-table

I have a clock table that matches on tags, and that works fine:

```
#+BEGIN: clocktable :match "meeting" :scope ("~/org/journal/Journal 2021-04.org")
```

But I would like to be able to tie my clock tables into [org roam](https://www.orgroam.com/) by matching on links, so I can avoid having both roam links *and* tags in the same place; something like:

```
:match [[some link]]
```

I was reading about [matching tags and properties](https://orgmode.org/manual/Matching-tags-and-properties.html#Matching-tags-and-properties), and this section is similar to what I want:

> Instead of a tag, you may also specify a regular expression enclosed in curly braces. For example, ‘work+{^boss.*}’ matches headlines that contain the tag ‘:work:’ and any tag starting with ‘boss’.

But it explicitly only (?) allows for regular expressions that match on tags. I *think* I found where the match tags are parsed in `org-clock.el`, but I'm an elisp novice and it feels dangerous to modify an internal function like `org-clock-get-table-data`.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for (matching on links) without modifying `org-clock-get-table-data`?